# FlatList testing using Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs, enzyme

How to test FlatList using Jest and Enzyme? I cant figure out how to check if it has got keyExtractor or not.

```
    it('flatlist should have keyExtractor', () => {


        wrapper
            .find('FlatList')
            .props()
            .keyExtractor();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass the item in `.keyExtractor()` to test the return. For example:

If you have:

```
<FlatList 
  data={data}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
/>
```

Now the test:

```
it('should flatlist return keyExtractor correctly', () => {
 const key = wrapper
             .find('FlatList')
             .props()
             .keyExtractor({id: 3});

expect(key).toEqual('3')
});
```